# How to make Electron based application handle AppleScript events and define sdef interface?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-forge

I have an Electron based application that I want to be able to communicate with using **AppleScript**.

I can't find any way to inject an `sdef` file into the build process or how to handle/process **AppleScript** events even if I did.

Is this possible within the *Electron* framework?

Comment: Is this project : https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript helping you ?

Comment: @J4Y-M no, I actually already use `node-applescript` for sending *AppleScript* to other apps but it doesn't (as far as I can see) allow me to define incoming *AppleScript* commands _to_ the application. If I could figure out how to add the `sdef` file into the build process I could define my own AS commands